# Showing $H= \{v \in H^1(I) \ | \ v(0)=0 \} \subset H^1(I)$ is a Hilbert space

Tags: proof-verification, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $I$ be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

We define $H= \{v \in H^1(I) \ | \  v(0)=0 \} \subset H^1(I)$ with the scalar product of the Sobolev space $H^1(I)$, i.e. $(u,v)=(u,v)_{L^2(I)}+(u',v')_{L^2(I)}$.

> I want to show that $H$ is a Hilbert space. We already know that $(u,v)$ is a scalar product in $H$. We have to show that $H$ is complete i.e. $H$ is closed on $H^1(I)$.

We pick a convergent sequence $(v_n) \subset H$ such that $v_n \to v$. We want to show that $v \in H$. As $(v_n)$ converges in the norm $||\cdot ||_{H^1(I)}$ and $$||v_n||_{L^{\infty}(I)} \leq ||v_n||_{H^1(I)}$$  (Sobolev embedding) then $v_n \to v$ uniformly. Then, as $v_n(0)=0$, $v(0)=0$.

In one dimension $v$ has a continuous representative. **Then** $v(0)=0$. Otherwise $v(0) $ might be non defined.

Comment: does it mean that if $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(I)$ then $\int_0^x u_n(t) dt \to \int_0^x u(t) dt$ in $L^\infty(I)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I don't get your point.

Comment: it is $\sim$ what you wrote. Let $w_n(x) = \int_0^x u_n(t) dt$. if $u_n \to 0$ in $L^2(I)$ then $w_n \to 0$ in $H^1(I)$ and $\|w_n\|_{L^\infty(I)} \le \|w_n\|_{H^1(I)} \to 0$. and by considering $w_n = v_n-v$ you are done

Comment: What about my proof?

Comment: it is the same, just I wrote explicitely how $v_n(0) = 0$ is well-defined, and I looked at $v_n-v$ which $\to 0$ in $H^1(I)$, so it $\to 0$ in $L^\infty(I)$ too

Comment: Okay, you used Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Thanks. I have used the fact that $u$ has a continuous representative, a basic result of Sobolev spaces in one dimension.

Comment: you don't need, consider $v_n-v$ instead of $v_n$, that's all, write that $\|v_n-v\|_{H^1(I)} \to 0$ so that $\|v_n-v\|_{L^\infty(I)} \to 0$ and $0 = v_n(0) \to v(0)$

Comment: @user1952009 That's what I have done, but $||\cdot||_{L^{\infty}(I)}$ is the essential supremum, so we need continuity, otherwise the supremum converges almost everywhere.